# Speech enabled asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, speech

We are working on an asp.net web application that requires some data to be entered by speech.

The user can enter some data using normal user interface however, we want an additional feature where he can enter data by speaking. We can fix the voice commands like to enter "value1" to "data1", user will speak "data1" followed by "value1" (or anything else, that can be fixed later).

I searched over the internet and found that using Microsoft Speech SDK is a solution. We started with some initial implementation and found that it only works with IE and requires a plugin (we were not able to use this plugin in Windows 7, just XP).

Is there any other solution or can SASDK be used for other browsers as well ? Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks,
Gaurav

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done:

1. Use HTML5's getUserMedia to capture an audio stream
2. Save it to .WAV, there are libraries for that
3. Send the .WAV to the server through AJAX
4. Feed the .WAV to SpeechRecognitionEngine, through the SetInputToWaveFile method
5. Get the result and return it in the AJAX call

An example:

http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/speech-recognition-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

Please read: [Whatever Happened to Voice Recognition?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/06/whatever-happened-to-voice-recognition.html)
Its **not possible** as of now unless you are doing an academic project.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave this idea. It is not possible to recognize arbitrary values from arbitrary people. There are some more or less successful projects (like Google Voice Search) but they are proprietary, closed and not for sale. The cost to create such system will be estimated in millions of dollars.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use Dragon Naturally speaking for this, they have an SDK and an internet explorer plugin.

http://www.nuance.com/naturallyspeaking/pdf/ds_DNS10_SDK_Client.pdf

http://ct.scansoft.com/customerfiles/kbasefiles/3067/wp_DNS_HTML.pdf

I think its designed primarily for traversing the web pages but if there is an option to handle custom voice commands then I dont see why you could not fill a text box with the command name for example.

might not be able to provide what you need but certainly worth checking out if you have not already

Comment: Our next step was to use Dragon. We are into it currently, hope we have something positive out.