# Speech recognition online (similar to google voice search)

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I am been trying to find a mehthod for online speech recognition, for eg: very similar to [google voice search](http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/voicesearch/index-chrome.html), which does not require the user to install any plugin/software/flash. The user just has to plugin the microphone and speak something for the text to get recognised.

I thought of this approach but don't know if this is corrector not. I built a dll which can take an input audio stream and give an output of recognized txt out of audio. I referenced this dll in ASP.NET references, and further thinking to upload an audio file from the user side to the server which will then be used the 'recognizer' dll. I am not sure if this approach is correct or not? Is there any other approach that I can follow? 
The main thing is I can't have the user install anything or any dependency for this implementation such as flash/silverlight etc.

Comment: See my answer: Speech enabled asp.net application [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805221/speech-enabled-asp-net-application/27153153].

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805221/speech-enabled-asp-net-application/27153153.

Answer (score 1):

If you can specify that your users use Chrome 11, or later, you could use Google's webkit to speech enable your application. Here is a [link on how to use webkit for speech](http://www.phpied.com/x-webkit-speech-input-and-textareas/). This leverages the audio input capabilities that are available in [HTML5](http://slides.html5rocks.com/#speech-input). If you take a look at [this blog](http://mikepultz.com/2011/03/accessing-google-speech-api-chrome-11/) it will explain how it works, because the author reverse engineered it. It is taking the audio input from the user in the browser and sending it to a service for processing, returning the results as a JSON message. You could build your own service on the server side, as you are suggesting, to imitate what Google is doing.  Building a scalable service for speech recognition will not be a small feat.