# How to implement Speech Recognition in C# ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, speech-recognition

I want to use speech recognition in C# ASP.NET where

1) I want to allow the user to speak the hotword

2) Validate the hotword and based on the hotword, the user should be given with the appropriate portal.

I came to know that the "System.Speech" namespace is not available for web applications and this could be done using Silverlight. I'm new to Silverlight technologies, so can anybody help me out or suggest me with some alternate ways to achieve the goal.

Comment: See my answer: Speech enabled asp.net application [1].

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805221/speech-enabled-asp-net-application/27153153.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this link out to start out with:

[MSDN - Get Started with Speech Recognition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361683%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

And this, too, for Silverlight speech API:

[Having fun with Silverlight 4 Beta and the Speech APIs](http://www.davidezordan.net/blog/?p=1575)